# Saving Textfile even if User uninstall the application

Tags: android

I am making an android application where during the time of installation a text file of mode_private is saved in the internal storage, but when user unistalls the app, the text file also gets deleted. I want the text file not to be deleted, so if user reinstalls the app, that text file could be used. I found out this could e done if the file is saved in external storage, but if user unmounts the external storage, this might create a problem, so I need to save the file in internal storage. How can I do this??

My snipet for writing and reading the file are

**writing file**

```
 try{
        FileOutputStream fileout=openFileOutput("userdata.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
        OutputStreamWriter outputWriter=new OutputStreamWriter(fileout);
                    outputWriter.write(phone.getText().toString());
                    outputWriter.close();
 }catch(Exception e){}
```

**reading file**

```
try {
        FileInputStream fileIn=openFileInput("userdata.txt");
        InputStreamReader InputRead= new InputStreamReader(fileIn);
        char[] inputBuffer= new char[READ_BLOCK_SIZE];
        String s="";
        int charRead;

        while ((charRead=InputRead.read(inputBuffer))>0) {
            // char to string conversion
            String readstring=String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer,0,charRead);
            s +=readstring; 
        }

        InputRead.close();
        register.setText(s);

} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Save the file on a server.

Comment: thank you for your idea but i think saving it as a text file will be lot easy.. so one doesn't need to go to server for such task... so any more ideas

Comment: not easy in real. if you are thinking unmount external storage, then you may also worry that user delete the file with File Manager app.  so save to server if it really important, or save to external storage. i suggest.

Comment: You can simply **copy** your text file to a server each time a change happens or by user request (backup). Then, in case of need (restore), download it again. You can use the DropBox API.

Comment: Thank you both... I did the same way as you said :) seems like saving in server might help me in many more ways in my application